# qtreewidgetitem addchild to already present item yields nothing

Tags: c++, qt

I have two QTreeWidgetItem that are top level. I want to make the second the parent of the first. Calling the first one's addChild(second item) shows no change. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: What do you want to exactly do? What do you expect to see when adding the second as child of the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to remove the item you want to reparent first using `takeItem()`, and subsequently add it as a child to the new parent item.